# Fastify stops in production mode

Tags: node.js, server, graphql, apollo, fastify

Hello I want to run fastify with react build files for front-end. I don't know why when I run my server, it stops after running.

> yarn run v1.22.10 $ node dist/src/index.js Server is ready at port
> 4000 Done in 3.03s.

my code:

```
app.register((instance, opts, next) => {
  instance.register(fastifyStatic, {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    prefix: "/*/",
  });
  next();
});

server.start().then(() => {
  app.register(server.createHandler({ path: "/graphql", cors: corsOptions }));
  app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Server is ready at port 5000");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Who is the server variable? You should check for the error argument in your listen callback

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon got the error but the problem is that it wont redirect all the routes to build folder

Comment: could you share the stacktrace?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Thank you for your patience. I have managed to redirect all to my react build. But now I have issue with playground. I can still access playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. But I still have access to playground. Will update if I figured it out.

```
app.register((instance, opts, next) => {
  instance.register(fastifyStatic, {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    prefix: "/",
  });
  instance.setNotFoundHandler((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", path.join(__dirname, "build"));
  });
  next();
});
```